# Нескольких IP адресов внутренних и внешних на Debian?

Tags: сеть, debian, администрирование, unix

У нас в компании имеется 3 интернет провайдера
У них есть шлюзы

```
192.168.0.100 - Провайдер №1, Внеший IP 92.126.213.101
192.168.0.102 - Провайдер №2, Внеший IP 92.126.213.102
192.168.0.103 - Провайдер №2, Внеший IP 92.126.213.103
```

В локальной сети Есть сервер на Debian.
Ему выделено 3 IP адреса

```
192.168.3.98 - маска подсети 255.255.248.0
192.168.3.97 - маска подсети 255.255.248.0
192.168.3.96 - маска подсети 255.255.248.0
```

Суть всего, надо чтобы если пропал интернет на одном провайдере, можно было обратиться к серверу через другой внешний IP.

В Debian открыл файл /etc/network/interfaces
и туда прописал конфиг

```
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.3.98
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 192.168.0.101

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.3.97
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 192.168.0.102

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 192.168.3.96
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 192.168.0.103
```

Но в итоге при обращении на все три внешние IP открывается только один.
Если по очереди отключать все IP адреса на локальном сервере в конфиге и оставлять только один, то все нормально работает.

Если из локальной сети пытаться открыть 192.168.3.98, 192.168.3.97, 192.168.3.96 - все открывается корректно

Нужно в итоге, чтобы трафик распределялся по всем трем провайдерам одновременно.
Трафик идет на nginx на 80 порту

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том что пакеты приходят с разных провайдеров, а шлюз по умолчанию только один. Вам надо настроить классический source-based routing. Делается с помощью iproute2. Вот достойный [пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/107267/)

Привожу пример на ваших данных.

```
# echo 100 eth00-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# echo 101 eth01-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# echo 102 eth02-route >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

И приводим конфигурацию /etc/network/interfaces к следующему виду:

```
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.3.98
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 192.168.0.101
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.0.100 dev eth0:0 table eth00-route
post-up ip rule  add from 192.168.3.98 lookup eth00-route

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.3.97
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 192.168.0.102
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.0.102 dev eth0:1 table eth01-route
post-up ip rule  add from 192.168.3.97 lookup eth01-route

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 192.168.3.96
netmask 255.255.248.0
gateway 192.168.0.103
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.0.103 dev eth0:2 table eth02-route
post-up ip rule  add from 192.168.3.96 lookup eth02-route
```

Надеюсь вам поможет.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Прописал Как вы написали, читал статью, к сожалению только по одному IP прокинулся трафик. Если рассказать суть, то у нас в локальной сети стоит 3 роутера разных провайдеров, все роутеры в одной подсети 255.255.248.0 , сам сервер имеет адрес 192.168.3.98, если поставить маску подсети 192.168.0.101 будет интернет №1, поставить маску подсести 192.168.0.102 будет интернет №2 и  поставить маску подсести 192.168.0.103 интернет №3.  Может быть мои адрес 98,97,96 избыточны. Есть ваш личный контакт ? как связаться ? Я согласен платно даже получить консультацию, сил уже нет